# SequelizeEagerLoadingError: product is not associated to collection

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use sequelize ORM in Mysql. I have 3 Models: Product, Collection, CollectionProduct

relationship between Product and Collection are many to many and for handle this in sequelize i used **belongsToMany** association. every thing is Ok but when i run this code to get a collection with its products with **include** Eager this error occure:

*SequelizeEagerLoadingError: product is not associated to collection!*

**Product Model:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
id: {
  allowNull: false,
  autoIncrement: true,
  primaryKey: true,
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
name_en: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
},
description_en: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(1024),
},
price: {
  type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
  allowNull: false,
},
type: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
},
height: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
width: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
createdAt: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  allowNull: false,
},
updatedAt: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  allowNull: false,
},
}, {})

Product.associate = (models) => {
Product.belongsToMany(models.collection, { through: models.collectionProduct, as: 'collections', foreignKey: 'productId' })
}

return Product
}
```

**Collection Model :**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const Collection = sequelize.define(
'collection', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name_en: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
  },
  itemsCount: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}, {},
)
Collection.associate = (models) => {
Collection.belongsToMany(models.product, { through: models.collectionProduct, as: 'products', foreignKey: 'collectionId' })
}
return Collection
}
```

**CollectionProduct Model:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const CollectionProduct = sequelize.define('collectionProduct', {
collectionId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
productId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
createdAt: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  allowNull: false,
},
updatedAt: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  allowNull: false,
},
}, {})

CollectionProduct.associate = (models) => {}


return CollectionProduct
}
```

***routes/collection.js***

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

const Collection = require('../../controllers/collectionController')

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
 const { id: collectionId } = req.params
 const collection = await Collection.getOne(collectionId)
 return collection
}
```

**collectionController**

```
const db = require('../models/index')

const Collection = db.collection
const Product = db.product

const getOne = async (collectionId) => {
   const collection = await Collection.findByPk(collectionId, {
      include: {
      model: Product,
      as: 'products',
      attributes: ['id', 'name_en'],
   },
  })
return collection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. in collectionController i used model: Product
and Product should be a sequelize model. but in my code this is a function that have been called in models/index. so i changed my calling and pass a sequelize model to getOne